# CWinApp dll file giving prob with CWinApp class

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am trying to link a `dll` file to my project in the `MFC template` with simple calling it and including the header file. But i am getting a `assertion failure` whenever i am trying to make an object of the header file of my `dll` Class.
Both the classes are `CWinApp`, i further debugged and found that both the `mfc WinApp` applications are trying to call the same `afxgetThread()` function which is resulting in a `assertion failure`. Can anyone help me out here ? 
Thank you.

[image: assertion failure getafxThread()]

[image: Assertion Failure warning]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [CWinApp: The Application Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx):

> An application built on the framework must have one and only one object of a class derived from [`CWinApp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362kaah4.aspx).

Comment: So even if i am linking a seperate dll i cannot call another cWinApp class in the dll function if i am making one in the main program ?

Comment: @Hadi The documentation is fairly explicit here: One `CWinApp` per **application**, not per **module**. `CWinApp` is implemented as a singleton and stores application-wide state. Asking for a second instance doesn't seem to make much sense.